# problem while installing app on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

H everyone

i have up graded my `xcode` to `xcode 4` & i am trying to install a app through this xcode on to a iphone but i am getting following error & i am unable to launch the app

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /var/mobile/Applications/7A08B9EA-DD46-47B4-8E0C-BF081BDB1F4B/QIA All.app/QIA All (file not found).

dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/7A08B9EA-DD46-47B4-8E0C-BF081BDB1F4B/QIA All.app/QIA All

Reason: image not found
```

i have following warning in my app
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Developer/new xcode/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks'

is from this warning

how can i fix this?,,,thanx in advance

Comment: may be in resource folder some image is not copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check that all images and framework are included friend. may b any image is missing that is deleted from project folder .check if you get any image in red then add that image

Comment: ya i checked that ,,all images r present(no red images)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app is still trying to link to the 3.1.2 SDK.  You need to change the SDK in the project settings to Base SDK: Latest (iOS 4.3).  Also make sure to clear out any settings in the target for this value so that it inherits it properly.

Comment: actually i have installed xcode 4 in a newly created directory called newxcode  inside developer directory (developer/newxcode) ,,is that cause any problem?,should it be inside developer only?

Comment: No, I often move the location of my install directory, so that I can continue to use older versions of Xcode on my machine.